# Increasing TextBox Height without Increasing Font Size

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, textbox, controls

I have a UserControl in my Application and a TextBox is fitted on it with property ***Docking.Fill***

I have a situation where I dynamically grow the windows/Forms size ,in that case all my controls get re-sized as per the new ratio, but my text box's height doesn't change.

Solution 1:
I have to set the Font Size to increase height , but the issue is, It re-sizes all the controls which are used in my application, also some text in controls overlaps.

I want other way that without affecting the Font Size, i can grow my TextBox in Height without using **Multiline = True**.

It would be great if any body help,

Comment: The size is determined by the UserControl.  By whatever you did with it in the form, which you did not document.  Setting a single-line's TextBox.Dock property to Fill is just plain wrong, the TextBox loses its ability to resize itself to fit the font.  This almost surely went wrong when you derived your class from UserControl instead of TextBox.

Comment: A UserControl, A TextBox and Label on it,Label for Shadow when TextBox length = 0, right.I have a function which finds all the controls in UserControl or Form and adds them to a List of Control, then I re-size each and every control with given aspect ratio for increasing in Load_event of Form/UserControl, right. The Issue was that, although my TextBox's Docking was Filled It was not Re-sizing by manipulating its Height*Factor, That's why I have asked the question,Now I have done by just using TextBoxControl.AutoResize = false and then using Size property.That was what i wanted to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this in designer file

```
this.textBox1.AutoSize = false;
this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
```

MSDN > [TextBoxBase.AutoSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I have to change this size during run-time, as I have mentioned, Dynamic re-sizing of controls

Comment: Yes on the  `AutoSize = false;` part but you would want the sizing to be done with DockStyle or something.

Comment: @DareDevil - this code is very much aimed at runtime.

Comment: @Pranay Rana : Right , I have tested it, its Fine , But I have tested other way right that Increase its FontSize along with Height, Code help from "Code Project"

Answer (score 2):

A Custom Function which re-sizes the Font with a Aspect Ratio and Increase the height of TextBox.

```
public void IncerseHeightTextBox(TextBox tb, float Aspect_Ratio_Height)
    {
        tb.AutoSize = false;
        tb.Width = (int)(tb.Width * (1.402+1.171)/2); //Width+height Ratio /2
        tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font.FontFamily, tb.Font.Size * Aspect_Ratio_Height);
        tb.Size = new Size(tb.Width, (int)(tb.Height * Aspect_Ratio_Height));
    }
```

And Function call here:

```
IncerseHeightTextBox(tb2, (float)1.171);
```